# git move repository with branch

Tags: git, github

I am going to move the project from the old repository to the new repository. And I tried to move the repository with the following command.

```
git clone --mirror {git Repository path}
mv repositoryToCopy.git .git
git remote set-url origin {new repository path}
git push --mirror
```

It succeeded in moving to a new repository, but only the master branch and its commit history were moved. I want to bring all the branches from the old repository. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have access to both repositories on GitHub?

Comment: The reason I ask is because GitHub has the ability to transfer ownership.

Comment: @astrochun Unfortunately not now.

Comment: The `--mirror` options *should* have resulted in a complete copy. (Note, however, that after sending the full copy with `--mirror`, you generally want to stop using the mirror clone. But that's *after* you verify that it all worked, and apparently it didn't all work. We can't see from your question what went wrong, though.)

Comment: You might check this [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository), clone with --bare